# Unable to use swagger in spring application

Tags: java, spring, swagger, spring-rest

I have followed the steps mentioned in https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api to add swagger to a plain spring application -

I added the maven dependencies -

```
<!-- for swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- end of swagger dependency -->
```

I created 2 classes for configuration -

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringFoxConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringFoxUIConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

but It is not working
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Add a `/` at the end of your url.

Like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-rest-demo/swagger-ui/
```

Comment: Hi, just tried this, but its still not working.